# How to convert json keys into small letters?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to convert json keys into small letters as the object are built from strings that are gathered using inconsistent letter case for the keys. I tried the following:

```
import json

alphabet = """{"My-Name": "ag=11", "Rule": "default"}"""
alphabetDict = json.loads(alphabet)
alphabetDictKeys = alphabetDict.keys()


for key, value in alphabetDict:
    smallalphabetDict[key.lower()] = value

smallalphabetDictKeys = smallalphabetDict.keys()
print("small keys:"+str(smallalphabetDictKeys))

# if statement using small case letters
if "my-name" in smallalphabetDictKeys:
    print("key found")
    print("value"+str(smallalphabetDict["my-name"]))
```

But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 11, in 
>   for key, value in alphabetDict: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Can you please correct me where my code is wrong in the conversion?

Comment: `for key, value in alphabetDict.items():` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import json

alphabet = """{"My-Name": "ag=11", "Rule": "default"}"""
alphabetDict = json.loads(alphabet)
alphabetDictKeys = alphabetDict.keys()
smallalphabetDict={}

for key, value in alphabetDict.items():
    smallalphabetDict[key.lower()] = value

smallalphabetDictKeys = smallalphabetDict.keys()
print("small keys:"+str(smallalphabetDictKeys))

# if statement using small case letters
if "my-name" in smallalphabetDictKeys:
    print("key found")
    print("value"+str(smallalphabetDict["my-name"]))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to iterate through dictionary use dict.items()

```
for key, value in alphabetDict.items():
    smallalphabetDict[key.lower()] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in your code

- You need to use `alphabetDict.items()` to iterate on a dictionary
- `if "my-name" in smallalphabetDict:` should be able to iterate on the keys, you don't need `smallalphabetDictKeys = smallalphabetDict.keys()` for it
- You are not using `alphabetDictKeys = alphabetDict.keys()` anywhere in your code, you can remove that line

The changed code will look like

```
import json

alphabet = """{"My-Name": "ag=11", "Rule": "default"}"""
alphabetDict = json.loads(alphabet)

#Iterate of the keys and lower them
smallalphabetDict = {}
for key, value in alphabetDict.items():
    smallalphabetDict[key.lower()] = value

# if statement using small case letters
# Iterate on the keys again
if "my-name" in smallalphabetDict:
    print("key found")
    print("value"+str(smallalphabetDict["my-name"]))
```

The output will be

```
key found
valueag=11
```

You can also simplify your code via dictionary comprehension, and using `dict.get` to get your item

```
import json

alphabet = """{"My-Name": "ag=11", "Rule": "default"}"""
alphabetDict = json.loads(alphabet)

#Iterate of the keys and lower them via dictionary comprehension
smallalphabetDict = {key.lower(): value for key, value in alphabetDict.items()}

#Use dict.get to get the value for the key
print(smallalphabetDict.get("my-name"))
```

The output will be

```
ag=11
```

Answer (score -1):

check this code

```
import json

alphabet = """{"My-Name": "ag=11", "Rule": "default"}"""
alphabetDict = json.loads(alphabet)
alphabetDictKeys = alphabetDict.keys()

smallalphabetDict = {}
for key in alphabetDict:
    value = alphabetDict[key]
    smallalphabetDict[key.lower()] = value

smallalphabetDictKeys = smallalphabetDict.keys()
print("small keys:"+str(smallalphabetDictKeys))

# if statement using small case letters
if "my-name" in smallalphabetDictKeys:
    print("key found")
    print("value"+str(smallalphabetDict["my-name"]))
```